# Function using vectors crashes, debugger says Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Before I say anything, let me post my code.

```
string formatNumber(llint num){
        if (num <= 999) return to_string(num);
        vector<char> c;
        for (int i = 0; i <= to_string(num).length()-1; i++) {
            c.push_back(to_string(num)[i]);
        }
        auto it = c.end();
        for (int i = c.size() - 1; i >= c.size() - 1; i--) {
            if (i >= 3 && i % 3 == 0) {
                it = c.insert(it + i, ',', 1);
            }
            it--;
        }
        string Return;
        for (int i = 0; i <= c.size(); i++) {
            Return += c[i];
        }
        return Return;
    }
```

The point of this function is to format a number with more digits than three, to make it readable with more ease. Like so: 1000 would become 1,000. Basically it adds a comma every 3 digits from the left. My problem is how my program crashes and throw this exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC24A2C447 (vcruntime140.dll) in RESL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000223F53C2000.
```

No clue on how this can be resolved, would you, kind people of stack overflow help me?

Comment: Off by one error.  In `for (int i = 0; i <= c.size(); i++)` you run the range `[0, size()]` while a vector only has a valid range of `[0, size())`.  `i <= c.size() -> i < c.size()`.

Comment: There are two types of programmers, those who make off by one errors.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver that is not only error, it == end() and it + i used, whole code is a mess.

Comment: your loops look... no offense... really weird. E.g. `for (int i = c.size() - 1; i >= c.size() - 1; i--) {` it takes a while to see that this loop isnt really a loop. I strongly suggest you to use iterators when iterating containers and when looping with an index it helps a lot to make all your loops look like this `for (int i=0; i<M; i++){` (of course it is a matter of style, but I really mean ALL your loops without exception)

Comment: In other news, when you've fixed the off-by-one error, this code will still be nasty. You could just use `string Return(c.begin(), c.end());` in the first place. You call `to_string` _and then discard the resulting string_ all over the place.

Comment: you do not need vector of char - string works that way, that would eliminate half of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `std::vector<char>` as `std::string` by itself has all functionality you need. Using string would eliminate most of your code and you only need one loop:

```
std::string s = std::to_string( num );
const auto size = s.length(); // we need to keep it as it would change on insertion
for( size_t i = 3; i < size; i += 3 )
    s.insert( size - i, 1, ',' );
```

Comment: Thanks to you I found out that vector functions work for strings as well, also my function works now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many errors in your code, for example:

1. The first thing you need to know is that iterators may be invalid when you perform insert/delete operations on the sequential container.
2. The statement `i <= c.size()` in the last `for` loop should be `i < c.size()`.

Actually, you don't need to use another `vector<char>`. Just use the string generated by `to_string` is enough.

Comment: "The statement i < c.size() in the last for loop should be i < c.size()." didn't you just say the same thing 2 times?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be: The statement `i <= c.size()` in the last for loop should be `i < c.size()`.

Comment: No worries :) I appreciated your help anyways.